# Grunt usemin + filerev not replacing an image tag with the rev'ed version

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm newer to grunt and I started with the yeoman generator-angular and restructure my project and now i'm trying to get the grunt build to play nice again.

Here's the output of my `grunt build`

[image: Grunt output]

and I have this html tag in one of my views:

`<img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" />`

but it doesn't work after grunt build because it doesn't get replaced with the rev'ed version. Do i need to add those usemin comment blocks around this somehow do I need to update my gruntfile to handle this?

Full Gruntfile.js

```
// Generated on 2014-10-29 using generator-angular 0.9.8
'use strict';

var pkg = require('./package.json');

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    //app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
        app: __dirname,
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js', 
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/controllers/{,*/}*.js', 
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/factories/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/filters/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.app %>/js/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:all'],
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'karma']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['newer:copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/img/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/controllers/{,*/}*.js', 
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/factories/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/filters/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/js/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath:  /\.\.\//
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              //js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              js: ['concat'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/img']
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
                options: { cache: false },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/img',
          src: '{,*/}*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/img',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // ng-annotate tries to make the code safe for minification automatically
    // by using the Angular long form for dependency injection.
    ngAnnotate: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: ['*.js', '!oldieshim.js'],
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}*.html',
            'img/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'font/*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/img',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
       }
       //,
      // css: {
      //   expand: true,
      //   cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/css/compiled',
      //   dest: '.tmp/css/compiled/',
      //   src: '{,*/}*.css'
      // }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      test: [
        'copy:styles'
      ],
      dist: [
        'copy:styles',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: true
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }

    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:test',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    //'concurrent:dist',
        'copy:styles',
                //'copy:css',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngAnnotate',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    //'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

Comment: there are errors in bash? previous build where working ?

Comment: no errors. i've never gotten a build to work, but i never tried to run a build before restructuring things.

Comment: sorry but i'm a little bit confused.. Assuming that you used the command `yo angular` to start the project how did you obtain the dist folder ? btw the command to copy the files from the app folder to the dist folder is ` grunt copy:dist`. Try it.

Comment: I started with yo angular, but have restructured the app heavily b/c I didn't care for the folder structure. Why do I care about `grunt copy:dist`? I'm trying to figure out how to replace an image with the rev'd version. aka `logo.png` to `logo.23489089023.png`

Comment: I was caring about `grunt copy:dist` because i didn't understand you removed the `app` folder.

Comment: Did you fix it at the end?

Answer (score 1):

The tasks that take care for the rev are `filerev` and `usemin`.

So try to run the following commands:

```
grunt filerev
grunt usemin
```

In particular if you run `grunt filerev` in according to your Gruntfile.js will go to rename the files you specified in  `filerev:dist:src`

```
// Renames files for browser caching purposes
filerev: {
  dist: {
    src: [
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/img/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
      '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
    ]
  }
},
```

Assuming that `yeoman.dist` is the folder `dist` it will take care of all the images in `dist/img/*.[png|jpg|jpeg|gif|webp|svg]` .
So you should see the `logo.png` to `logo.23489089023.png` happening.

For update the img html tag you have to use `grunt usemin`.
For this task you don't need any special block ([documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-usemin)).
You have just to setup `usemin:html` and `usemin:options:assetsDirs`.

But again in your Gruntfile.js you have :

```
// Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
usemin: {
  html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
  css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
  options: {
    assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/img']
  }
},
```

Which is good actually because is going to replace in all the html and css files in the `dist` folder all the rev'd assets.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar problem until I realised that my `usemin` config was slightly wrong. The current config only checks for `html` files **1 level deep** meaning that if you have `views/folder/file.html` it will never be updated.  Instead, change your config to use the 0 or more glob, `**`.

```
html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html']
```